# Expand Datastore Question

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I added storage to my LUN and want to expand the datastore in vCenter. Is it as easy as running the Expand wizard? Can it expand on the fly with VM's running? Do I need to backup my VM's before I do this? Will I lose and data?

This is a production array and I can't afford anything to happen to the data on this array. I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's that easy and yes it can safely be done 'live', though the VMs may momentarily pause for a very short period of time as you do the expand so you may wish to schedule it to happen at a time of low usage. You may also wish to backup your VMs first if you wish.

Comment: I'd still recommend having backups up to date and checked before doing it. I know it's supposed to work and probably will, but if it's important...I'd rather waste the time making backups and having them than leaving it to chance.

Comment: I second the suggestion to do it at a low I/O time. The applications that'll have problems with this kind of operation will be the ones that are sensitive to I/O lags. This operation will introduce one, and you don't want other normal traffic to make the lag worse.